# How do I determine the last letter I deleted in "del" button?

Tags: android, eclipselink

After deleting the letter using "del" button in TextView. I want to determine the letter that has been deleted.

Comment: What have you already tried? If you have tried something, edit your question to include the relevant section of your code. If not, please try something, because SO won't write your code for you.

Comment: TextView or EditText? recommend you to try textchangelistener.

Comment: if(riddleanswer.getText().toString().isEmpty()){}
    else{String text = riddleanswer.getText().toString();
          riddleanswer.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
          riddleanswer.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);}}

Comment: i want to get the letter that i just deleted. i created a delete button that can  delete the last letter of the textView. My problem is the deleted letter is not coming back from the button.

Answer (score 1):

Use TextChangedListener (TextWatcher()) ... get string to variable beforeTextChanged() ... then check if variable length has decreased on onTextChanged() ... if yes yo can get last character of that string is deleted character.

String entered_text;
 addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
       enteredText = s.toString();
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.toString.length < enteredText.length){
       //Now get last char of enteredText here .. which is deleted currently
      }
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **onEditorActionListener** to find out if the user has pressed the DEL key and then get the character at the current cursor postition:

```
final EditText editText = new EditText(this);

editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if(keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            char deletedCharacter = textView.getText().charAt(editText.getSelectionStart());
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

info:
make your editText object final or declare it global in order to access it within the listener.